# How to fetch data in NextJS from external API, but there's a session

Tags: reactjs, jwt, fetch-api, next.js13, next-auth

I have a problem with fetching user's data to my NextJS frontend application from my backend REST API.

As I mentioned the entire application consists of separated frontend (React/NextJS 14) and backend REST API (Java/Springboot).

Authentication looks like this:

1. frontend sends correct username and password to backend
2. backend creates and sends back a JWT
3. frontend creates session with Next-Auth library and save the JWT, userId and userRole to a session.

Now when the user is authenticated and session is created I want to fetch the user's data from backend. I have prepared an API endpoint `/batches/{userId}`. It is necessary to add JWT in the request header (*Authorization: Bearer "JWT"*) and userId as a URL parameter. These informations are in session.

If I want to read informations from session it's needed to use `useSession()` from `next-auth/react`. This function works only in client component (with 'use client').
Fetch is used with `async` and `await` but it's not supported in client components. So, how to solve that with best practices?

Simply put in my component I need to read informations with useSession() from session, add these informations to request and fetch data from backend. How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could write an async function and call the function. since you want to do client side authentication fetching, you should be doing it inside `useEffect` so you would get the information before your component mounts.

```
const {data:session}=useSession()

useEffect(()=>{
   async function fethUserInfo(){
   // send request here using session information
   // add more logic
   }

   // call the function
   fetchUserInfo()
},[add correct dependency here])
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the data in next-auth, but store it in cookies and access from there. there's no reasoon to use next-auth in your case, maybe for social login, but you could also do that from your backend (you should have only 1 source of truth)

Edit:
you can also use getServerSession from next-auth but I don't think you should use next-auth

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from "pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]"

export default async function Page() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 2)}</pre>
}
```